# which kind of testing is required for this scenario

Tags: testing

software product is integrated and complete ,now to check whether it meets the intended specifications and functional requirements specified in requirements documentation:-

integration testing or functional testing or user acceptance testing

Comment: You didn't really give us any info besides "it needs testing". Each of the things you mention (integration,functional,acceptance testing) are very different beasts, can you be a bit more specific what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This sounds like homework or an interview question

Comment: For me this sounds like a valid question

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a discussion in many projects. What is the scope of the different test phase and I think you ask a very valid question I have discussed very often in projects.

The answer is opinion because I have read different answers in different books and standards and it also depends on the size of the software and the kind of the software.

[Here are good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370334/difference-between-acceptance-test-and-functional-test)

In my world normally integration testing is to see whether it works with all up-stream and down-stream systems while functional testing is done on a system alone. But often the functional testing is an end-to-end test and cannot be done standalone so the integration and functional testing becomes the same test phase.

user acceptance testing usually is done by someone else and is the client who gives his sign-off and does his own set of test cases.