# Unit-testing remote methods of a strongloop loopback.io model

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node, strongloop, loopbackjs

I am trying to write unittests for a loopback model using jasmine. My model has the usual CRUD endpoints but I have defined a custom '/products/:id/upload' endpoint which expects a form with files.

My model looks like

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');

var ProductSchema = {
    location: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    version: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    id: { type: Number, id: 1, generated: true }
};

var opts = {
    strict: true
};

var dataSource = loopback.createDataSource({
    connector: loopback.Memory
});
var Product = dataSource.createModel('Product', ProductSchema, opts);


Product.beforeRemote('upload', function(ctx){
    var uploader = function(req, res){
        // parse a multipart form
        res({
            result:'success'
        });
    };
    function createProduct(uploaderResult){
        // create a product out of the uploaded file
        ctx.res.send({
            result: uploaderResult.result
        });
    }
    uploader.upload(ctx.req, createProduct);
});

Product.upload = function () {
    // empty function - all the logic takes place inside before remote
};

loopback.remoteMethod(
    Product.upload,
    {
        accepts : [{arg: 'uploadedFiles', http: function(ctx){
                        return function() {
                            return { files : ctx.req.body.uploadedFiles, context : ctx };
                        };
                    }},
                   {arg: 'id', type: 'string'}],
        returns : {arg: 'upload_result', type: String},
        http: {path:'/:id/upload', verb: 'post'}
    }
);

module.exports = Product;
```

My end goal is to test the logic of the "createProduct".
My test looks like

```
'use strict';

describe('Product Model', function(){
    var app = require('../../app');
    var loopback = require('loopback');
    var ProductModel;
    beforeEach(function(){
        app = loopback();
        app.boot(__dirname+'/../../'); // contains a 'models' folder
        ProductModel = loopback.getModel('Product');
        var dataSource = loopback.createDataSource({
            connector: loopback.Memory
        });

        ProductModel.attachTo(dataSource);
    });

    it('should load file ', function(){
        console.log(ProductModel.beforeRemote.toString());
        console.log(ProductModel);
        ProductModel.upload();
    });
});
```

By calling ProductModel.upload(); I was hoping to trigger the before remote hook which would exercise the the createProduct. I could test "createProduct" in isolation but then I would omit the fact that createProduct ends up being called as a result of upload.

To be perfectly clear, the core question is: 
How do I exercise remote method hooks inside unittests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was suggested to use [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) as an http server. Below there is a code snippet illustrating how to do it in jasmine

```
describe('My product suite', function(){
    var request = require('supertest');
    var app;

    beforeEach(function(){
        app = loopback();
        // don't forget to add REST to the app
        app.use(app.rest());
    });

    it('should load file', function() {
      request(app).post('/products/id-of-existing-product/upload')
        .attach('file', 'path/to/local/file/to/upload.png')
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          // res is the HTTP response
          // you can assert on res.body, etc.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there fixtures, so i can generate a guest instead of having to register?

Comment: I am not sure what needs to be registered. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: For example, registering a user, and logging in to get an auth token. It would be convenient to have fixtures in these situations instead of making a series of requests every time.

Comment: shouldnt the `app` variable be declared outside of the `beforeEach` function, so it would be available to supertest inside of the `it`.  Also, I keep getting a 404 instead of 200 using this test.  Any idea why?

Comment: can you please udpate the answer with the context from the original question? There is no sign in this answer of including the model that the OP wanted to test.

Comment: Is this considered a unit test? It looks like a functional test to me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741836/6651596