# TestCafe framework usage

Tags: testing, devexpress, e2e-testing, functional-testing, testcafe

Does anyone have the exact idea on Devexpress TestCafe tools?

What I have found that "User can get the JavaScript codes, which has been created on the test page at the time of recording. User can directly copy-paste those codes in any other projects."

But I am not sure that if a user can execute his/her own project in TestCafe or not. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you contact the DevExpress Support directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe is a functional web testing framework. It is intended for creating and performing functional web tests. You can learn more about functional testing and TestCafe in particular from these links:

[Unit tests vs Functional tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741832/)

[TestCafe Documentation](http://testcafe.devexpress.com/Documentation)

[TestCafe Studio, a cross-platform IDE for end-to-end web testing](https://testcafe-studio.devexpress.com/)

[What is the difference between a paid and an open-source TestCafe version? What is TestCafe Studio?](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/faq/#what-is-the-difference-between-a-paid-and-an-open-source-testcafe-version-what-is-testcafe-studio)