# How to get default symfony3 functional test to pass?

Tags: phpunit, symfony, functional-testing

I started to explore symfony3 and after install I run the provided functional test via

```
phpunit
```

on the terminal, but I get the error:

```
1) Tests\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testIndex
Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 200.
```

Hitting the page via browsers works.

What needs to be changed in settings to have this test pass?

Comment: check in the `var/log/test.log` files for further details.

Comment: cool thanks now makes sense!

Comment: hi @fefe have you solved?

Comment: yes I had previously added FOSUserBundle but not configured and this is what I got in test.log `request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: "Bundle "FOSUserBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. `. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sidenote about wording: Even though you run the tests via phpunit, it's not a unit test but a functional test as you test the functionality of the site via a php browser, and not the output of methods for a certain input. [You may want to read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741845/457268)

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to this particular line:

```
$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

It is expecting an html response code of "200" but instead you are getting '500', which is "Internal Server Error".

Comment: I realized that but why is dropping that? as I said if I access via bowser is okay

Comment: pass response's content as third argument to the assertion (the message) to get the page output on failed test: `$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), $client->getResponse()->getContent());`