# How to test angular get request?

Tags: angular, angular6

I would like to test get request related functionality.
Request should be fired and values mapped to relevant object.
Related code is:

```
it('Should have values set', () => {
  const service: FetcherService = TestBed.get(FetcherService);
  const technologyString = 'technology';
  service.fetchNews(technologyString);
  expect(service.fetchNewsResponse.category === technologyString);
});
```

Currently it however may not be relevant as relatated test fails with Karma and message is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
```

What should I change in code to fix this issue?

edit:

Code related to service.fetchNews is:

```
public fetchNews(category: string) {
this.httpClient.get<News>('http://localhost:8080/news/' + this.country + '/' + category + '/')
.subscribe(data => this.fetchNewsResponse = data );
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `FetcherService` code ? Maybe `fetchNews` is asynchronous and the assertion is done before `fetchNewsResponse` is set ?

Comment: @JuniorDussouillez I added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has something to do with the API's response. Test if you get any error by defining an error handler in your GET request like:

```
public fetchNews(category: string) {
this.httpClient.get<News>('http://localhost:8080/news/' + this.country + '/' + category 
+ '/')
.subscribe(data => {
this.fetchNewsResponse = data
},
 error => { console.log('Error:', error); }
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, at least part of issue was related to fact that Karma's tests were running on different port than application - and server did not had relevant setup for handling this. I also added `await delay(2000);` related code to test and issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues are two-fold.  First, you are attempting to read data that has not yet returned (asynchronously) from the server.  But more importantly, you are attempting to do an end-to-end test in a unit (or functional) testing environment.  [Difference between functional test and end-to-end test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762575/difference-between-functional-test-and-end-to-end-test)

For unit testing a service that makes http calls with httpClient, using the HttpClientTestingModule and HttpTestingController give you the greatest flexibility.  See the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

In your case the final result should look something like this:

```
describe('FetchNews Service', () => {
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
            providers: [ FetcherService ]
        });
        httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    });
    it('should have values set', async(() => {
        const service: FetcherService = TestBed.get(FetcherService);
        const technologyString = 'technology';
        const responseData = {category: technologyString};
        const country = 'italy';
        service.fetchNews(technologyString);
        let req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:8080/news/' + country + '/technology/');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        req.flush(responseData); // send responseData as result of the get
        expect(service.fetchNewsResponse.category).toEqual(technologyString); // may need to be tested after observable resolves.
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already accepted another one however upvoted this one too.