# e2e testing angular 7: Failed: Cannot read property 'fetchData' of undefined

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular2-observables, angular-e2e

I'm trying to do some e2e testing for my service in angular 7, the method return Observable, this is my methode:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UrlDecoratorService } from "../../common/url-decorator.service";
import { APIFetcherService } from "../common/api-fetcher.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IALChrono, ALChrono } from '../../common/IALChrono.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AnnonceChronoDetailService {
    private months: string[];
    constructor(private urlDecoratorService: UrlDecoratorService, private apiFetcher: APIFetcherService) {
    }

    fetchData(chronoInfo: ALChrono): Observable<any> {
        // construct API parameters and URL
        var URL: string = this.urlDecoratorService.urlAPIDecorate("AL", "GetAccessChrono");

        var params = this.urlDecoratorService.generateParameters({
            year: chronoInfo.year,
            month: chronoInfo.month,
            sortBy: chronoInfo.sortBy,
            sortDirection: chronoInfo.sortDirection,
            pageNumber: chronoInfo.currentPage,
            pageSize: chronoInfo.pageSize
        });

        return this.apiFetcher.fetchJson(URL, params);
    }
}
```

and this is my test :

```js
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { AnnonceChronoDetailService } from '../../src/app/services/annonce-legale/annonce-chrono-detail.service';
import { ALChrono } from '../../src/app/common/IALChrono.interface';
import { APIResponse } from '../../src/app/common/api-response.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;
  let service: AnnonceChronoDetailService;
  this.chronoInfo = new ALChrono(); //it's a class

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('Welcome to MyProject!');
  });


  it('#getObservableValue should return value from observable', (done: DoneFn) => {
    service.fetchData(this.chronoInfo).subscribe((resp: APIResponse) => {
      expect(resp.dataCount).toBe(5);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

and this is my terminal error :

```js
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53112/devtools/browser/2a1d94b2-ef47-4910-9ee2-e875b615ed45
Jasmine started

  workspace-project App
    √ should display welcome message
    × #getObservableValue should return value from observable
      - Failed: Cannot read property 'fetchData' of undefined
          at UserContext.<anonymous> (D:\Front\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts:34:13)
          at new ManagedPromise (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1077:7)
          at ControlFlow.promise (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2505:12)
          at TaskQueue.execute_ (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
          at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
          at asyncRun (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2974:25)
          at D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
          at <anonymous>
      From: Task: Run it("#getObservableValue should return value from observable") in control flow
          at ControlFlow.emit (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\events.js:62:21)
          at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2674:10)
          at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (D:\Front\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2599:53)
      From asynchronous test:
      Error
          at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\Front\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts:33:3)
          at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Front\e2e\src\app.e2e-spec.ts:7:1)
          at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
          at Module.m._compile (D:\Front\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:439:23)
          at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
          at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (D:\Front\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:442:12)

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) workspace-project App #getObservableValue should return value from observable
  - Failed: Cannot read property 'fetchData' of undefined

Executed 2 of 2 specs (1 FAILED) in 6 secs.
[10:02:20] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[10:02:20] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[10:02:20] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[10:02:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
```

i want to test the real value of my return methode not like the unit testing, and they don't know my method **fetchData**.

if you need some more information please tell me.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created an instance of `AnnonceChronoDetailService` (just the reference is created), that is why `service` variable is undefined

```
let page: AppPage;
let service: AnnonceChronoDetailService;
this.chronoInfo = new ALChrono(); //it's a class

beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
    service = new AnnonceChronoDetailService(); // create service instance
});
```

Comment: yeah, i try to do that, but  the class **AnnonceChronoDetailService** need parameters like **UrlDecoratorService** and **APIFetcherService**, i don't know how to pass it.

Comment: If you are simply mocking the method, then you can always pass null to it like `service = new AnnonceChronoDetailService(null, null);`

Comment: i do that and i have this problem **Failed: Cannot read property 'urlAPIDecorate' of null** and i do `service = new AnnonceChronoDetailService(new UrlDecoratorService(),null);` and i have this problem **- Failed: Cannot read property 'fetchJson' of null**,  and i do that  `service = new AnnonceChronoDetailService(new UrlDecoratorService(),new APIFetcherService(new Http(new ConnectionBackend(),new RequestOptions())));` and i have this problem **- Failed: sessionStorage is not defined**

Comment: I already said, only if you are mocking the method, then it works. I am not sure how services are injected in e2e testing similar to `TestBed.get()` in unit testing.