# How to inject services in e2e testing angular (protractor)

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

i need to inject two services to my e2e test to test my service, first **UrlDecoratorService** second is **APIFetcherService** how to do that in e2e testing (protractor)?

this is two question i posted to understand my problem.

[first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337670/angular-e2e-testing-how-to-test-service-injectuse-another-services)

[second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335638/e2e-testing-angular-7-failed-cannot-read-property-fetchdata-of-undefined)

and right know i don't find the solution.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? You *don't* inject services in e2e tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular e2e testing : how to test Service inject(use) another services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337670/angular-e2e-testing-how-to-test-service-injectuse-another-services)

Comment: yeah it's my post , just i want to give a global idea of my project, but how can i test my service(get the real data) by e2e testing? i'm very confused.

Comment: This is not what protractor is for. Protractor is for automated UI tests. What you want is an integration test. That's jasmine, has absolutely nothing to do with protractor. I looked at your second post to see what you are trying to do. I mean this in the nicest way possible...you're doing it wrong.  You might want to visit the [protractor docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/getting-started) to see what protractor is meant for.